# SSRS 2008 R2 Report taking lot of time to load

Tags: reporting-services

SSRS 2008R2 report loads fast on test reporting server but takes lot of time on production server. How should I fix this problem.
Scenario:
I created a report for inventory transactions for a ERP application on my local BIDS environment and set the defaults and preview the report. I see no issues but when I deploy to production and click on the report, it take lot of time to open the report.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does report pull data from the same DB in Dev and Prod? Perhaps the size of data is the issue?

Comment: It is different data and different server.

Comment: Can you get a copy of that Prod DB to your local system and test the load?